# Right margin of custom clear button in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I create a custom clear button on my text field with a background image set.
I position it on the right view but it always positions with a default margin. What I want is to have a right margin, for example, of 8.

```
extension UITextField {

    func clearButtonWithImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        let clearButton = UIButton()
        clearButton.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
        clearButton.alpha = 0.25
        clearButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)

        clearButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clear(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.rightViewMode = .always
        self.clearButtonMode = .never
        self.rightView = clearButton
    }

    @objc func clear(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.text = ""
    }
}
```

I use a custom textfield class for changing the style of my textfield on selecting.
My custom Textfield Class:

```
class customSearchTextField: customTextField {
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            setSelected(isSelected)
        }
    }

    private func setSelected(_ selected: Bool) {
        //UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, animations: {
        self.transform = selected ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05) : CGAffineTransform.identity
        self.cornerRadius = selected ? 2.0 : 0.0
            if selected {
                self.clearButtonWithImage(UIImage())
            } else {
                self.clearButtonWithImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icClear"))
            }
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor .customDark.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = selected ? 0.19 : 0.0
        //})
    }
}
```

Tried positioning the image frame but it always stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [rightViewRect(forBounds:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619638-rightviewrect) method. Create a subclass of `UITextField` and custom position and size of clear button inside this method.

For example

```
class customSearchTextField: customTextField {
  override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
      setSelected(isSelected)
    }
  }

  private func setSelected(_ selected: Bool) {
    //UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, animations: {
    self.transform = selected ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05) : CGAffineTransform.identity
    self.cornerRadius = selected ? 2.0 : 0.0
    if selected {
      self.clearButtonWithImage(UIImage())
    } else {
      self.clearButtonWithImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icClear"))
    }
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor .customDark.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = selected ? 0.19 : 0.0
    //})
  }

  override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var rect = super.rightViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
    rect.origin.x -= 30 // Assume your right margin is 30
    return rect
  }
}
```

Comment: I already use a custom class for my textfield that shows the clearbutton with image on selected and unsets the image, i update my question to see the code

Comment: Updated my answer, you can try it.